# How to remove a array from an array by comparing it with another array?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-5, multidimensional-array, foreach

I've 2 array as below. One array is a 2  dimensional array(`$array_1`) and another is a simple array (`$array_2`). This `$array_1` as a key called `private_name` in each array and `$array_2` has a list of `private_key` values. I want to keep the array from `$array_1` which matches with `$array_2`.

```
    $array_1 = [
        [0] => ['id'=>12, 'private_name' => 'name12', 'age' => '23'],
        [1] => ['id'=>2, 'private_name' => 'name2', 'age' => '23'],
        [2] => ['id'=>9, 'private_name' => 'name1', 'age' => '23'],
        [3] => ['id'=>11, 'private_name' => 'name11', 'age' => '23'],
        .
        .
        .
        [999] => ['id'=>999, 'private_name' => 'name999', 'age' => '23'],
   ];

   $array_2 = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3',....];
```

So i wante remove array contents from `$array_1` which matches with `$array_2`. Currently am using the below method but it takes a lot of time as there are 14k+ array values in  `$array_1`. Is there any soulution for this which just uses 1 line to solve the above. I want a solution like

```
$newVal = array_intersect(array_column($array_1, 'private_name'), $array_2);
```

Current am doing like below which takes a lot of time

```
$results = array();
    $count = 0;
    if (count($array_1) > 0) {
        foreach ($array_1 as $row) {
            foreach ($row as $col => $val) {
                foreach ($array_2 as $key3 => $pvt_name) {

                    if (strcmp($row['private_name'], $array_1) == 0) {

                        $results[$count][$col] = $val;

                    }
                }
            }
            $count++;
        }
    }
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be done using `array_filter`.

```
$filtered_array = array_filter($array_1, function($item) use($array_2) {
  return !in_array($item['private_name'], $array_2);
});
var_dump($filtered_array);
```

The callback function needs to return true to keep the item in the result, false to discard it. That is done here by checking if the `private_name` value of the item is contained in your second array - and the result of that negated, because you only want to keep those that *don’t* match.

Comment: thanks for the solution. Small change.. i wanted to keep the data which is available in $arrray_2. I'vve changed it in question. So i removed the neggate for this But the problem is it is taking a lot of time to process. I've about 14k+ arrays inside $array_1. Any solutions for that. Currently it is taking about 30-40 sec to execute that line

Comment: Well you can try the same thing by explicitly looping over the data yourself (_one_ loop over the outer level of array 1, in_array to check, and then inserting the item into the result array if you get a match), and then compare the performance or do some actual benchmarking … but that’s probably not going to change too much about how long this will take with such an amount of data.